# Net::ReadTimeout issues when opening pdf after moving from capybara-webkit to selenium-chromedriver

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, selenium-chromedriver, wicked-pdf

I updated my test environment from Capybara-webkit to Selenium and with  Chrome to test against a more modern browser. But now I have this issue with a test that opens a pdf in a new tab. I'm not sure what causes this problem.

```
click_on 'Print'
within_window windows.last do
  io = StringIO.new(page.body)
  strings = PDF::Reader.new(io).pages.map(&:text).join(' ').split(' 
')
  # Do some testing here.
end
```

When Print is clicked a pdf file is generated in a new tab.
I like to read the files content using the pdf-reader gem.
When I run this test I get a Net::ReadTimeout.
In my console I see some warnings for loading the .css and .js files:

Warning: Failed to load http:localhost:3000/assets/application-92d08a385444e234a36aeb5970e4fbbaf5a5c0130ccfcc429905fa333a588b32.css

This test worked just fine with capybara-webkit.
Any ideas how to resolve this issue?

Comment: are you running your local host server while running these tests?

Comment: Hi Aakash Gupta yes indeed i run the test locally.

Comment: can you please tell the commands you are using to run test?

Comment: ruby -I test path/to/file.rb -t test_name

Comment: When I test regular html pages everything works just fine.

Comment: It seems that you are trying this test on a html file that you are expecting your web-server to serve. As the test is going on and you web server is having only one thread, the request to serve this file sent by your test to server will not be completed and will cause a Deadlock for a single threaded Web server.

Answer (score 0):

Found it!
For those running into the same problem. ActionDispatch.SystemTesting.Server is registering a Puma server with 0:1 threads. For working with pdf's you need more then 1 thread.